# $|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant C|x-y|^{\alpha},\forall x,y\in(a,b)$ Prove that $f$ is constant in $(a,b)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ and assume that there is $C>0$
and $\alpha>1$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant C|x-y|^{\alpha},\forall x,y\in(a,b)$

Prove that $f$ is constant in $(a,b)$.

Prove that $\underset{x\to y}{\lim}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=0$

Ie $(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0):|x-y|<\delta\implies|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}|<\epsilon$

Suppose that $|x-y|<1$.

Then by the stated inequality, $\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}\leqslant\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}\leqslant C\iff\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}\leqslant C$.

I need to show that this is smaller than $\epsilon$ but I'm not too sure where to go from here.

Comment: What are the hypothesis on $\alpha$?

Comment: what's ur $\alpha$? Is it a real number ?, a positive number ?, greater that $1$?

Comment: Sorry, added hypothesis on $\alpha$

Comment: Hint: Note that $
\left| {\frac{{f(x) - f(y)}}{{x - y}}} \right| \le \left| {x - y} \right|^{\alpha  - 1} 
$ and $\alpha-1>0$ (by hypothesis).

Comment: More similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/361400